# Windows 7 installation disc fails to boot properly on UEFI

Tags: windows-7, boot, dvd, uefi

Whenever I try to install Windows 7 onto my laptop, the boot process simply stops and hangs at the boot splash. No error is given, and the splash continues to animate. However, it never progresses beyond this point. The firmware is UEFI, and the laptop model is a Gateway NE56R. The disk has 5 different partitions, the EFI system partition, the root filesystem of my Linux Mint 17.1 installation, the partition for my home directory, another partition for /usr/local, and one for swap space. I have not yet resized and repartitioned this disk for windows installation, and why bother if the installation disc won't even boot? The whole system is 64-bit, and so is Windows and the Linux installation.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit operating system?  32-bit or 64-bit UEFI? Update your question.

Comment: @Ramhound Done.

Comment: Your installation disk contains the required EFI drivers correct?

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean? There is indeed a /efi folder on the disk, if that is what you mean. However, it appears that my machine simple can not run Windows 7 because it does not have interrupt 10, according to the link provided in the first answer. No setting in firmware setup is provided to enable that, either. I might have to stick with Windows 8 instead.

Comment: I was asking you to verify the disk contains the drivers required to boot to it since your having trouble booting to it. If you can run Windows 8 you can run Windows 7

Comment: @Ramhound "If you can run Windows 8 you can run Windows 7", this is not true for UEFI boot. Read the KB article that I posted in my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same hang issue on my Dell 7520. Windows 7 requires the old VGA Option ROM to be able to boot, [otherwise it hangs at "Starting Windows"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2828074/en-us). Go into the UEFI setting and look if you can enable such a setting or disable the UEFI fast boot

Comment: These options do not exist on my machine. According to that article, it simply may not be possible.

Comment: please post the exact laptop model and post some pictures of the UEFI.

Comment: If I really wanted to, I could switch my UEFI to boot in BIOS mode and install Windows 7 from there, but then I cannot boot from GPT unless I switch back. I would need a new partition table, and I like my partition table where it is. So I installed Windows 8.1 instead. Another thing I noticed is that the installer disc did not contain a /efi/boot/bootx64.efi file. This is the file that is required to boot under EFI. Windows 7 was released before UEFI became popular, and it was usually found on servers and Macs. I don't know how the UEFI boot sequence has changed since then.

Comment: UEFI boot works since Vista ;) As I said, the issue is the GOP/VGA Option ROM issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Microsoft, I enabled CSM on my ASUS X79 and it worked (-;

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to believe you have deeper hardware issues if you cant load a boot disk. Try running some tests on your RAM, HDD, make sure the boot disk isn't scratched, try a different DVD drive...
Boot disks are loaded into your RAM, so I would start there.
[How Boot Loaders Work](http://lennartb.home.xs4all.nl/bootloaders/node3.html)

Comment: no, read the KB article that I linked in my answer.

Comment: Good answer, it is most likely the solution, however mine is still valid and could lead to a solution if yours doesn't.